# How to disable export button when i filter rows in gridview has no records found

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

In my application, I used Data Table plugin for filter rows in grid view if no records found in grid view when filtering the data that time only i need to disable export button. I used the below code for this but it is not working the button disable when i started filtering button disabled please help me to disable export button when filtering no records found in grid view. here filtering records using data table plugin

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of creating an instance of DataTable you need to declare a callback property that will call certain method everytime the datatable is redrawn, here if you can access datatable object then you can check for redrawn datatable length. If it's greater than 0 then show export else hide it.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        var api = this.api(); 
        var dataLength = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).data().length;
        if (dataLength == 0) {      
            document.getElementById('<%= btnExport.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= btnExport.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @suprabhat-biswal, It's working thanks a lot thank you so much. Is It possible to what i filter those records to export to excel sheet

Comment: You will have to do some workaround to achieve this purpose (export filtered record only). For this you need to persist what filter you have done and when making a server call to export data use these filter content to filter from big data again.

Comment: Hi @suprabhat-biswal, when i add the above code my export button not disable when i click gridview in edit button can you please tell me

Comment: Earlier you have used datatable.js to show a grid but now you have migrated from jQuery datatable to Asp.Net Gridview therefore above code won't work. What I shared was for jQuery datatbale not for asp.net gridview. Please see your [**Edits**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42106533/revisions).